# Standard/Wildly-Accepted Terminology for This Concept

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

In Blykh's *Module Theory*, the author introduced a special type of modules called ***$p$-modules*** or ***$p$-primary modules***. The definitions are as follows:

---

Let $R$ be a PID and $M$ an $R$-module. For each $a\in R$, let $$(0:_Ma):=\{x\in M\mid ax=0_M\}$$ be the set of elements in $M$ annihilated by $a$. Define $$M_a:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(0:_M a^n).$$ Suppose $p\in R$ is prime. Then $M$ is said to be *$p$-primary* or a *$p$-module* if $M=M_p$.

---

I searched the Internet but could not find any standard or widely-accepted terminology for this concept. Does anyone have good ideas?

Comment: Over $R=\mathbb Z$ these abelian groups are called $p$-primary, or just primary, according to Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-group

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks! I guess the author is generalizing this terminology to modules over PID as $\Bbb Z$ itself is a PID.

Comment: Yes, that seems likely. There is scant information in Wikipedia about the primary groups, so it seems a relatively rarely used terminology, compared to $p$-group and other like terms.